# How to get specific value and id from select options using if statement?

Tags: reactjs

If options's value is `X` then I'd like to put it in `labels`
and If option's value is `Y` then I'd like to put it in `data`.
So I tried like this:

```js
const [getId, setGetId] = useState([]);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

  const clickCheck = header => e => {
    setGetId([...getId, e.currentTarget.id]);
  };

  let axis = [
    info.map(i => i[getId[0]]).slice(1, undefined),
    info.map(i => i[getId[1]]).slice(1, undefined),
  ];
  let chartData = {
    labels: axis[0], //x값
    datasets: [
      {
        label: title,
        data: axis[1], //y값
        backgroundColor: [
         
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

```js
<MainRow>
                      {info.slice(0, 1).map(inf => (
                        <RowFirst>
                          {inf.map((d, index) => (
                            <div className="title">
                              <h5>{d}</h5>
                              <div className="select">
                                <select id={index} onChange={clickCheck(d)}>
                                  <option value="x">X</option>
                                  <option value="y">Y</option>
                                  <option disabled selected value></option>
                                </select>{" "}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        </RowFirst>
                      ))}
                    </MainRow>
```

and I want to get two things from select option.
if `axis[0]` complete then i want to add another data to `axis[1]` but i don't know how and i tried to search it long time but didn't get the answer please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe no value on select is the problem?

`<select value={...} onChange={this.handleChange}>`

In your case, you are using select id, not value.

IMHO